# Garbage Collection in C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vb.net, garbage-collection

I never programmed in C++ but while I am coding in C# I wanted to learn more about .NET Framework. .NET Framework is basically a library and run-time environment. That part is covered. But if .NET Framework supports multiple languages like C++, VB.NET, J# then the capabilities that are given for C# should be same for others.

So if C++ is a language that was supported by .NET Framework then it should have garbage collection. This also should be true other languages that are supported by .NET Framework.

I should gather the subject in two questions:

1- Does C++ have garbage collection? 
2- Do every programming languages that are supported by .NET Framework have all .NET Framework's capability?

Comment: 1. No. My understanding is that .NET uses a kind of C++-like hybrid language.

Comment: So, based on your comment, can we say that other programming languages that are supported by .NET Framework actually use somekind of hybrid language to connect with framework?

Comment: No, it may use languages that are designed to be used with the framework, ones that do support GC as an integral part of the language.

Answer (score 2):

1) Managed C++ use .NET garbage collection for managed resources.

Also check this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089147/does-c-have-a-garbage-collector)

Comment: Is Managed C++ and C++/CLI are same?

Comment: Then Visual Basic's situation is similar to C++. When Visual Basic first came up, .NET Framework hasn't been invented yet. So, Visual Basic.NET is like Managed C++. It's converted( or developed ) to another language in order to make it work with .NET Framework. Am I right?

Comment: I think the change C++ to managed C++ is bigger than the change VB to VB.NET, but yes you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the MSVC++ compiler allows you to write C++ code that can use the garbage collector.  The /clr compile option must be used to enable the proper code generation.

But you have to do more, one non-trivial thing that any garbage collector needs to do is discover object pointers that are stored on the stack or CPU registers.  That's a hard thing to do, practical C++ garbage collectors like Boehm's are *conservative* collectors.  The .NET collector is not, it requires that the runtime can discover *all* the pointers.

That required a number of changes in the traditional C++ build model and language syntax.  Most importantly, the C++ compiler translates code to IL instead of machine code.  That Intermediate Language gets just-in-time compiled at runtime to machine code.  A very important job performed by the jitter is that it builds a table at runtime that tells the collector where objects are stored, giving the GC a reliable way to discover a pointer back in a stack frame slot or CPU register.  This is almost entirely invisible, other than the side effect of not generating code that is as heavily optimized.  Mixing code that's compiled to IL with code that's compiled to machine code directly is well supported.

Not so invisible is the requirement that you must tell the compiler which pointers store a reference to a garbage-collected object.  You still use the `ptr*` syntax for normal pointers, but you must use the `ptr^` syntax for managed pointers.  And, like Boehms', you have to use a different allocator, using the `gcnew` instead of the `new` keyword.  Object references likewise are different, you use `ref%` instead of `ref&`.  And there's another flavor of arrays, you must use the `array<>` keyword to get an array that can reliably be checked by the GC for pointers.  Classes that are managed classes must be declared with the `ref class` instead of the `class` keyword.  And there's a grab-bag of additional extensions that permit using .NET specific features such as properties, events and delegates.

These C++ syntax extensions are called C++/CLI.  Ecma-372 is the language specification.

Answer (score 0):

C++ per se does not have garbage collection.

Managed C++, and the newer C++/CLI, does have garbage collection since it is part of .Net.

Not everything in every .Net language is supported by every other .Net langauge. There is a *common* language:

> "To fully interact with other objects written in any language, objects
>   must expose to callers only those features that are common to all
>   languages. This common set of features is defined by the Common
>   Language Specification (CLS), which is a set of rules that apply to
>   generated assemblies."

taken from [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3.aspx). ("Any language" means any .Net language.)

For example, the only unsigned integer type which meets the CLS is a `byte`.